# FacebookClient GetTaskAsync sometimes returns invalid JSON string(UWP 10)

Tags: c#, json, facebook, win-universal-app

i'm trying to get data from Facebook using the FacebookClient API.
However i sometimes get the error "Invalid JSON string".
The strange thing is that sometimes i do get data using the same task.

this is my code

```
    public async void GetData(String AccessToken, String task)
    {
        FacebookClient fbclient = new FacebookClient(AccessToken);
        try {
            var res = await fbclient.GetTaskAsync(task);//me/feed
            String data = res.ToString();
            /*IDictionary<string, object> o3 = (IDictionary<string, object>)await fbclient.GetTaskAsync(task);
            JsonObject o2 = (JsonObject) await fbclient.GetTaskAsync(task);*/
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
    }
```

var res = ... gives the error. i don't know why it sometimes works and another time it doesn't.

thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the string when it say that it is not a valid json string?

Comment: thanks for the response, it says NULL i don't get any data at all.

Answer (score 2):

The SDK recently stopped working in Windows 10 apps (UWP), but continues to work fine in Windows 8.1 apps.

It's been reported on the GitHub page of facebook-csharp-sdk. The cause is UWP's default to the newer HTTP/2 protocol which is causing problems. Unfortunately, there is no fix yet.

**UPDATE**: [There is a temporary solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oh1DL.png) where if you open Internet Explorer > Internet Options > Advanced > **Disable HTTP 1.1** and **HTTP 1.1 through proxy**, then the SDK will continue to work in UWP runtime. Obviously not a real solution to the problem, but it brings us one step closer to finding the underlying cause.

Comment: If you found this useful, please mark my response as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @AndrewAu Re commenting, this is actually a fine answer so no issues with adding it as an answer, that's what it should be :) However, in general, the commenting restriction is there for a reason so [please see this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead/214174#214174) for some elaboration on what you can do instead. Again, great answer.

Answer (score 1):

Those who are struggling to find a permanent solution on Windows UWP App integration with Facebook, here is an updated SDK.

In GitHub
https://github.com/Microsoft/winsdkfb

In Nuget.org
https://www.nuget.org/packages/winsdkfb/

You can either use this Github SDK or download the same from Nuget package.

After login, FBSession object contains Users complete information which can be a replacement of fbclient.GetTaskAsync("me").

Hope this helps